# How to sort an array of objects based on another array with conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can anyone help me know how to filter an array of objects based on another array holding multiple conditions.

Sample Array

```
const arrayToFilter = [
  {
    name: 'Renaldo Ca',
    screen_name: 'rca0',
    followers_count: 726,
    following_count: 752,
    location: 'Peru',
    verified: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Bobbette Dibling',
    screen_name: 'bdibling1',
    followers_count: 747,
    following_count: 613,
    location: 'Argentina',
    verified: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Obed Snelson',
    screen_name: 'osnelson2',
    followers_count: 466,
    following_count: 352,
    location: 'Russia',
    verified: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Elyssa Eastop',
    screen_name: 'eeastop3',
    followers_count: 888,
    following_count: 493,
    location: 'Uganda',
    verified: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Auroora Balogun',
    screen_name: 'abalogun4',
    followers_count: 688,
    following_count: 468,
    location: 'Brazil',
    verified: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Sarge Crosser',
    screen_name: 'scrosser5',
    followers_count: 218,
    following_count: 424,
    location: 'United Kingdom',
    verified: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Griswold Lardeur',
    screen_name: 'glardeur6',
    followers_count: 785,
    following_count: 122,
    location: 'South Korea',
    verified: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Edwin Goodlatt',
    screen_name: 'egoodlatt7',
    followers_count: 484,
    following_count: 611,
    location: 'Indonesia',
    verified: true,
  }
]
```

Array With Filter Conditions:

```
const conditions=[ 
    { 
        id: 'name', 
        operator: 'CONTAINS' 
        value: 'Bob', 
    },
    { 
        condition:'AND',
        id: 'followers_count', 
        operator: 'GTE' 
        value: 200, 
    }, 
    {
        condition:'AND',
        id: 'following_count', 
        operator: 'LTE' 
        value: 10,
    },
    {
        condition:'OR',
        id: 'verified', 
        operator: 'EQ' 
        value: true,
    } 
  ]
```

The following code gives the filtered array but logic for AND/OR execution messesup.

```
   const filterWithConditions = (arr, conditions) =>
      arr.filter((item) =>
        conditions.every(({ id, operator, value }) => {
          switch (operator) {
            case 'CONTAINS':
              return item[id].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            case 'GTE':
              return item[id] >= value;
            case 'LTE':
              return item[id] <= value;
            case 'EQ':
              return item[id].toString() === value.toString();
            default:
              return false;
          }
        })
      );
    
    
    let filteredData = filterWithConditions(data, filters);
    
    const alternateFilters = groupBy(filters, 'condition')['OR'];
    if (alternateFilters) alternateFilters.map((filter) => filteredData.push(...filterWithConditions(data, [filter])));
    const processedData = getUniqData(filteredData);
```

The code should return array filtered based on these conditions in with respect to the bitwise conditions too(AND/OR).
Please let me know the optimized code for this. Thanks in advance!

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-hooks-4bbsu

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Take one of those conditions, and **try to** turn it into a function that can be used with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Then edit this question with that code, and ask again. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How do you expect the *precedence* for these logical operators to be defined?

Comment: @Pavithran - and might I add, that was a really really good edit.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz Please find this link for reference. U might get a better view 

https://codesandbox.io/s/black-hooks-4bbsu

Comment: @Pavithran as already pointed out, the most important part (as you've discovered too) is the `condition` property. What should the final OR be applied in relation to? You need to go back to whoever gave you these requirements and find out the answer to that question.

Comment: @Adam Since each condition is independent, the precedence will be like the whole filtered array till n-1th condition and the last condition.Hope you get it

ex:( (((1st condition AND 2n condition) AND 3rd cond) OR 4th cond)

Comment: @Pavithran what you posted is not what independent means, the 3rd condition and 2nd condition are not independent in your statement. Independent would mean what I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is how the logic should be applied:

```
Where the name contains bob
 AND the followers count is gte 200

Where the name contains bob
 AND the following count is lte 400

Where the name contains bob
 OR the verified property is true
```

Based on the above assumption, I'd do it like this:

```
const result = (item,condition) => {
  switch(condition.operator) {
    case 'CONTAINS': return item[condition.id].contains(condition.value);
    case 'GTE': return item[condition.id] >= condition.value;
    case 'LTE': return item[condition.id] <= condition.value;
    default: return false;
  }
}

const results = arrayToFilter.filter(item => {
  const baseCondition = conditions[0];
  const baseResult = result(item,baseCondition);

  // if there's only one condition, early return
  if(conditions.length === 1) return baseCondition;

  return conditions.slice(1).some(c => {
     const r = result(item,c);

     switch(c.condition) {
       case 'AND': return baseCondition && r;
       case 'OR': return baseCondition || r;
       default: return false;
     }

  });


});
```

All this being said, the UI is confusing and should include the ability to nest conditions to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I did a small example. Change as you want. I put some comments for your understanding.

```js
// Initial data

const objs = [
  {
    a: "a a a",
    b: "b b b",
    c: "c c c"
  },
  {
    a: "a b a",
    b: "b b b",
    c: "c b c"
  },
  {
    a: "a a c",
    b: "b b c",
    c: "c c c"
  },
  {
    a: "a a b",
    b: "b b c",
    c: "c c c"
  },
];

const conds = {
  "like": (a,b)=>a.includes(b),
  "eq": (a,b)=>a===b
};

const ops = {
  "OR": (a,b)=>a||b,
  "AND": (a,b)=>a&&b
}

const qrys = [
  {
    col: "a",
    cond: "like",
    val: "b"
  },
  {
    col: "b",
    cond: "eq",
    val: "b b c",
    op: "AND"
  },
  {
    col: "c",
    cond: "eq",
    val: "b b c",
    op: "OR"
  },
  {
    col: "c",
    cond: "eq",
    val: "c c c",
    op: "AND"
  }
]

// Function

const filtered = objs.filter(obj=>{
  let ret = false;
  for(const qry of qrys) {
    // Actual value of the object
    const val = obj[qry.col];
    // Comparing it with the expected value by given condition
    const assert = conds[qry.cond](val, qry.val);
    // Applying logical operators.
    if(qry.op){
      ret = ops[qry.op](ret, assert);
    } else {
      ret = assert;
    }
  }
  return ret;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: use 4 conditions with AND, AND, OR, and update your code.

Comment: I like this concept better than my answer, but it's still unclear to me (and I'm certain it's unclear to the user using the UI the OP posted) how this logic should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a string and take `eval` for the data with the correct logical operators.

```js
const
    ops = {
        EQ: (a, b) => a === b,
        GTE: (a, b) => a >= b,
        LTE: (a, b) => a <= b,
        CONTAINS: (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().includes(b.toLowerCase()),
        AND: (a, b) => a && b,
        OR: (a, b) => a || b
    },
    filterBy = filters => o => filters.reduce((r, { condition, id, operator, value }) => (ops[condition] || ops.OR)(r, ops[operator](o[id], value)), false),
    data = [{ name: 'Renaldo Ca', screen_name: 'rca0', followers_count: 726, following_count: 752, location: 'Peru', verified: false }, { name: 'Bobbette Dibling', screen_name: 'bdibling1', followers_count: 747, following_count: 613, location: 'Argentina', verified: true }, { name: 'Obed Snelson', screen_name: 'osnelson2', followers_count: 466, following_count: 352, location: 'Russia', verified: false }, { name: 'Elyssa Eastop', screen_name: 'eeastop3', followers_count: 888, following_count: 493, location: 'Uganda', verified: true }, { name: 'Auroora Balogun', screen_name: 'abalogun4', followers_count: 688, following_count: 468, location: 'Brazil', verified: true }, { name: 'Sarge Crosser', screen_name: 'scrosser5', followers_count: 218, following_count: 424, location: 'United Kingdom', verified: true }, { name: 'Griswold Lardeur', screen_name: 'glardeur6', followers_count: 785, following_count: 122, location: 'South Korea', verified: false }, { name: 'Edwin Goodlatt', screen_name: 'egoodlatt7', followers_count: 484, following_count: 611, location: 'Indonesia', verified: true }],
    conditions = [{ id: 'name', operator: 'CONTAINS', value: 'Bob' }, { condition: 'AND', id: 'followers_count', operator: 'GTE', value: 200 }, { condition: 'AND', id: 'following_count', operator: 'LTE', value: 10 }, { condition: 'OR', id: 'verified', operator: 'EQ', value: true }],
    result = data.filter(filterBy(conditions));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval(). See Never use eval()!, below.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi, yes, yes. but this is the only approach which respects the conditions.

Comment: @NinaScholz - `the only approach which respects the conditions` that's not true. There are two viable answers (that produce different results) in this thread. The hardest part about answering this question is determining the intention of the logical operators.

Comment: @Adam, i interpret the conditions array like directly written condition, in above case like `c0 && c1 && c2 || c3`. this is only possible to use something like eval or to use a parser for the AST.

Comment: @NinaScholz - that's a valid interpretation, and your answer is the only one, so far, that answers the question using that logic. But it doesn't mean it's the only, or even (arguably) likely, interpretation.

Comment: now without `eval` but with the [wanted logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67451364/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-with-conditions/67451859#comment119222258_67451364) from op.

Answer (score -1):

```
const items = [
  {
    name: 'Obed bob Snelson',
    screen_name: 'osnelson2',
    followers_count: 466,
    following_count: 352,
    location: 'Russia',
    verified: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Elyssa Eastop',
    screen_name: 'eeastop3',
    followers_count: 888,
    following_count: 493,
    location: 'Uganda',
    verified: true,
  },
]

const conditions=[ 
    { 
        id: 'name', 
        operator: 'CONTAINS',
        value: 'Bob'
    },
    { 
        condition:'AND',
        id: 'followers_count', 
        operator: 'GTE',
        value: 200
    }
];

const conditionCount = conditions.length
const itemsCount = items.length;

const results = [];
for(let index = 0; index < conditionCount; index++) {
  for(let itemsIndex = 0; itemsIndex < itemsCount; itemsIndex++) {
    switch(conditions[index]['operator']) {
      case "CONTAINS":
          if(items[itemsIndex][conditions[index]['id']].includes(conditions[index]['value']))
            results.push(items[itemsIndex])
        break;
      case "GTE":
          if(items[itemsIndex][conditions[index]['id']] >= conditions[index]['value'])
            results.push(items[itemsIndex])
        break;  
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

I did not include all operators, but hey....you should be able to figure the rest out yourself I think :). It about the idea I propose.

Comment: You did not take into account the most important `condition` property.

Comment: That's true. Because I posted this answer before the "condition" property was added to the question. The conditions array I use in my answer was an excerpt of the the one he did use in his question.

Comment: That's false, the `condition` property was part of the question [from the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67451364/revisions)

Comment: Ah now I see.....the first condition array item did not and still does not have the condition property. Others do! Thats probable why I looked over it :). Well...that makes this question tougher to answer!